# Ignore a directory

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ignore

## Context

We can add use Tortoise to ask subversion to ignore a directory by using the integration user interface as follows:

1. Right click directory.
2. TortoiseSVN.
3. Add to ignore list.
4. SomeDirectory (recursively).

[image: TortoiseIgnore]

When it's done there is an alert:

[image: Done]

## Two questions:

1. How can we do this through the standard subversion command line?
2. Where does Tortoise persist the above ignore info for SomeDirectory. I.e., where is the global ignore list that contains this ignore entry?

## What Have I Tried

```
 [PowerShell]
 svn proplist -R . | select-string ignore
```

Comment: I find the global ignore list in the Windows registry, under `HKCU\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config\miscellany`. A quick test of adding a bogus extension to TSVN's global ignore list via the dialog you've shown indicates that the above registry entry was updated to include it. Tested with TSVN v1.9.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can set the property, in your example:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "WebAnalytics" .
```

If you have more than one property to add, you can use:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

2) It is stored at the properties of the according folder. The global ignore list is stored on your local machine at the registry:

```
 HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Tigris.org\Subversion\Config\miscellany
```

Comment: Where on my local machine is the global ignore list stored?

Comment: i added the link in my answer